# How do i scatter a 3d array using MPI_Scatterv?

Tags: c, mpi

I am trying to distribute a 16*16*3(X*Y*Z) array into 16 processes as 4*4*3 arrays. I have used MPI_Create_subarray to scatter the blocks. For row-major ordering of a 3D matrix, I have taken the elements in the contiguous allocation as [Z*(Y*i+j)+ k]. The displacements required for MPI_Scatterv were calculated from this. But the scattering is only successful for process rank 0. Is the problem arising from the allocation of the 3d array?

```
int N = 16;
    int d = 3;
    int NPROWS = 4;  /* number of rows in _decomposition_ */
    int NPCOLS = 4;  /* number of cols in _decomposition_ */
    int BLOCKROWS = ROWS / NPROWS;  /* number of rows in _block_ */
    int BLOCKCOLS = COLS / NPCOLS; /* number of cols in _block_ */

    int* data = malloc(N * N * d * sizeof(int));
    int*** array = malloc(d * sizeof(int**));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = (int**)malloc(N * sizeof(int*)) ;
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            array[i][j] = &(data[(i * N + j) * d]);
        }
    }

    int* data2 = malloc(BLOCKROWS * BLOCKCOLS * d * sizeof(int));
    int*** array2 = malloc(d * sizeof(int**));
    for (int i = 0; i < BLOCKROWS; i++) {
        array2[i] = (int**)malloc(BLOCKROWS * sizeof(int*));
        for (int j = 0; j < BLOCKCOLS; j++) {
            array2[i][j] = &(data2[(i * BLOCKCOLS + j) *d]);
        }
    }

    if (rank == 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                 for (int k = 0; k < d; k++) {
                    array[i][j][k] = (d*(i*N +j)+ k) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }           
        
    MPI_Datatype mysubarray;
    MPI_Datatype mysubarray2;
    int starts[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };
    int subsizes[3] = {BLOCKROWS, BLOCKCOLS,d};
    int bigsizes[3] = {N, N, d};
    MPI_Type_create_subarray(3, bigsizes, subsizes, starts, MPI_ORDER_C, MPI_INT, &mysubarray2);
    MPI_Type_create_resized(mysubarray2, 0, 1 * sizeof(int), &mysubarray);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mysubarray);

    int* disps3d = malloc(NPROWS * NPCOLS * sizeof(int));
    int* counts3d = malloc(NPROWS * NPCOLS * sizeof(int));

    for (int ii = 0; ii < NPROWS; ii++) {
        for (int jj = 0; jj < NPCOLS; jj++) {
            disps3d[ii * NPCOLS + jj] = d*(ii * N * BLOCKROWS + jj * BLOCKCOLS);
            counts3d[ii * NPCOLS + jj] = 1;
        }
    }

    MPI_Scatterv(array, counts3d, disps3d, mysubarray, array2, (BLOCKCOLS*BLOCKROWS*d), MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: NOTE: it's s16 x 16 x 3 (X, Y,Z)  and 4 x 4 x 3 .

Comment: The displacements between the blocks are not regular, so you must use `MPI_Scatterv()`

Comment: I have used MPI_Scatterv() in the code. The displacements have also been calculated from  [Z*(Y*i+j)+ k] ordering of contiguous 3D arrays. But it doesn't seem to work out.

Comment: Only process 0 is receiving the scattered block correctly when I print the output. Does it must mean that the displacement is wrong?

Comment: both counts and displacements are wrong. The units are in number of datatypes, and extent of that datatype. That means `counts3d` should only contain `1`. Since you are sending only one datatype per task, the simplest option is to `MPI_Type_create_resized(mysubarray, 0, sizeof(int), ...)`, send this datatype and keep the existing `disps3d` array.